# How to split a string in JAVA with two different seperators?

Tags: java, string, split

Suppose, I want to split

2018910, abc , 45

by seperators ',' and ' ' simultaneously, what should I do?

Comment: In your specific case, you can split by `,` and trim the strings.

Comment: Trim in a sense..????

Comment: trim the white space, use the `trim()` method on String class.

Comment: Thnk u very much... :)